# Outlook Gmail Flag Error

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail, gmail-imap, flag

I'm using Outlook 365 to manage my Gmail IMAP accounts and have this annoying problem where when you flag and then unflag an email item an error comes up:

"The operation cannot be performed because the message has been changed."

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to say this is a known issue with a IMAP account in Outlook. I saw the same behavior in my Outlook. This error happens because Outlook is syncing with the server. You can try selecting a different message then switch back to the original message and you should be able to unflag messages without error.

Comment: Your way actually works. I tried multiple solutions available online but neither have worked. This simple trick seems to work. Thanks.

Comment: My pleasure :-)